# Retrofit GET without a value in Android

Tags: android, json, get, retrofit, retrofit2

I use Retrofit for most of my calls but in one of the cases, I have the full path provided in arguments. My URL is like this http://www.example.com/android.json. This URL is provided in full so I have to path it at runtime. I implement endpoint as suggested here
https://medium.com/@kevintcoughlin/dynamic-endpoints-with-retrofit-a1f4229f4a8d
but in the `@GET` I need to be able to put `@GET("")`. This does not work as I get an error saying I should provide at least one "/".

If I add the slash the URL becomes http://www.example.com/android.json/ and it does not work, the server returns forbidden. I also tried creating a custom `GET` interface similar to here https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/458 but with `GET` and without providing a value method in the interface. Then I get another error saying value is missing.

Basically I need to be able to provide an empty or null value but retrofit does not allow that. How could I solve this problem? For now I am doing the JSON request manually but is there a way I could use retrofit for this case? I need to pass the full URL there is no way I can do endpoint http://www.example.com and `@GET("/android.json")`.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url I think we maybe need Retrofit 2.

Answer (score 24):

You can use **@GET(".")** to indicate that your url is the same as the base url.

```
@GET(".")
Observable<Result> getData(@Query("param") String parameter);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1567#issuecomment-180115150) approach, however didn't work for me.

Workaround for this issue is:

```
//Retrofit interface
public interface TestResourceClient {
    @GET
    Observable<Something> getSomething(@Url String anEmptyString);
}

//client call
Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("absolute URL").build()
.create(TestResourceClient.class).getSomething("");
```

The downside of this solution is that you have to supply empty string in `getSomething("")` method call.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem with Retrofit 2. Using `@GET`, `@GET("")` and `@GET(".")` not solved my problem.

According to the [official document](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html) you can the same `baseUrl` and `@GET` argument.

> **Endpoint values may be a full URL.**
>
> Values that have a host replace the host of baseUrl and values also with a scheme replace the scheme of baseUrl. 
> Base URL: http://example.com/ 
> Endpoint: https://github.com/square/retrofit/ 
> Result: https://github.com/square/retrofit/

So in my case:

```
interface MyAPI {
    @GET("http://www.omdbapi.com/")
    suspend fun getMovies(
        @Query("apikey") apikey: String,
        @Query("s") s: String
    ): Response<MoviesResponse>

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(): MyAPI {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://www.omdbapi.com/")
                .build()
                .create(MyAPI::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```