# Retrofit 2 - Dynamic URL

Tags: android, retrofit

With Retrofit 2, you can set a full URL in the annotation of a service method like :

```
public interface APIService {
  @GET("http://api.mysite.com/user/list")
  Call<Users> getUsers();
}
```

However, in my app, the URL of my webservices are not known at compile time, the app retrieves them in a downloaded file so i'm wondering how i can use Retrofit 2 with full dynamic URL.

I tried to set a full path like :

```
public interface APIService {
  @GET("{fullUrl}")
  Call<Users> getUsers(@Path("fullUrl") fullUrl);
}

new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl("http://api.mysite.com/")
  .build()
  .create(APIService.class)
  .getUsers("http://api.mysite.com/user/list"); // this url should be dynamic
  .execute();
```

But here, Retrofit doesn't see that the path is actually a full URL and is trying to download `http://api.mysite.com/http%3A%2F%2Fapi.mysite.com%2Fuser%2Flist`

Any hint of how I could use Retrofit with such dynamic url ?

Thank you

Comment: For future searchers, there is a guide on dynamic URLs with Retrofit: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests

Comment: same problem but way better answers in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211672/using-retrofit-to-get-url-from-different-relative-paths

Answer (score 514, accepted):

I think you are using it in wrong way. Here is an excerpt from the [changelog](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-200-beta1-2015-08-27):

> New: @Url parameter annotation allows passing a complete URL for an endpoint.

So your interface should be like this:

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET
    Call<Users> getUsers(@Url String url);
}
```

Comment: @pdegand59 It's brand new :) see [changelog](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Why baseurl is required though the url for the endpoint is a fullurl?

Comment: If I use this @Url annotation. Then What should we write in .baseUrl() ??

Comment: you should write your primary url. @Url parameter will override it anyway.

Comment: Yazazzello For changing base url dynamically how to write @Url in APService?

Comment: @Yazazzello can you please help me out in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018534/retrofit-2-errorjava-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-object-but-was

Comment: @GulnazGhanchi you must use it when for example one of your api get data from another server, it means you have two or more base url.

Comment: any way to append a suffix here itself, after @url ?

Comment: I tried adding the URL like the one above but the baseUrl that i normally set for the retrofit builder overides the full url i specified in the parameter so instead of it being http://dynamic.com it gets translated to http://MyBaseUrl/http://dynamic.com

Comment: Can you still use Get("some/endpoint") with @Url? I want to have a base URL be dynamic but still use the retrofits parameters queries and so on. I don't want to manually construct them everytime

Comment: What if I don't know the Respone Model

Answer (score 204):

I wanted to replace only a part of the url, and with this solution, I don't have to pass the whole url, just the dynamic part:

```
public interface APIService {

  @GET("users/{user_id}/playlists")
  Call<List<Playlist> getUserPlaylists(@Path(value = "user_id", encoded = true) String userId);
}
```

Comment: Voted up. It helped me a lot using retrofit2 `suspend fun getUserPlaylists(@Path("id") id: String): YourOwnResponse`. Thanks

Comment: Got to know the difference between `@GET("users/{user_id}/playlists")` VS `@GET("/users/{user_id}/playlists")`

Comment: @ELITE It just a matter of whether you included "/" at the end of the base URL or not.

Answer (score 52):

You can use the **encoded** flag on the `@Path` annotation:

```
public interface APIService {
  @GET("{fullUrl}")
  Call<Users> getUsers(@Path(value = "fullUrl", encoded = true) String fullUrl);
}
```

- This will prevent the replacement of `/` with `%2F`.
- It will not save you from `?` being replaced by `%3F`, however, so you still can't pass in dynamic query strings.

Comment: It is not a typo.

Comment: and what to do to replace %3F with ?

Comment: for `?` you can't handle it manually. You should use `@Query` like this `@Query("page") number: Int` to pass query parameters. You can add multiple parameters aswell

Comment: This saved my day !

Comment: additionally, you can have more fields using:

@GET("{fullUrl}/{id}")
    fun getData(
        @Path(value = "fullUrl", encoded = true) fullUrl: String,
        @Path(value = "id", encoded = true) id: String
    ): Call<Data>?

Comment: adding link: https://www.baeldung.com/retrofit-dynamic-url

Answer (score 22):

As of Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2, if you have a service responding JSON from this URL :
http://myhost/mypath

The following is not working :

```
public interface ClientService {
    @GET("")
    Call<List<Client>> getClientList();
}

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://myhost/mypath")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

ClientService service = retrofit.create(ClientService.class);

Response<List<Client>> response = service.getClientList().execute();
```

But this is ok :

```
public interface ClientService {
    @GET
    Call<List<Client>> getClientList(@Url String anEmptyString);
}

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://myhost/mypath")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

ClientService service = retrofit.create(ClientService.class);

Response<List<Client>> response = service.getClientList("").execute();
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use this :

> `@GET("group/{id}/users")`
>
> `Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @Query("sort") String sort);`

For more information see documentation https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: piece of cake answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Dynamic URL with Get and Post method in Retrofit (MVVM)

**Retrofit Service interface:**

```
public interface NetworkAPIServices {

@POST()
Observable<JsonElement> executXYZServiceAPI(@Url String url,@Body AuthTokenRequestModel param);


@GET
Observable<JsonElement> executeInserInfo(@Url String url);
```

**MVVM service class:**

```
   public Observable<JsonElement> executXYZServiceAPI(ModelObject object) {
    return networkAPIServices.authenticateAPI("url",
            object);
}

 public Observable<JsonElement> executeInserInfo(String ID) {
    return networkAPIServices.getBank(DynamicAPIPath.mergeUrlPath("url"+ID)));
}
```

and Retrofit Client class

```
 @Provides
@Singleton
@Inject
@Named("provideRetrofit2")
Retrofit provideRetrofit(@Named("provideRetrofit2") Gson gson, @Named("provideRetrofit2") OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {


   builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
    if (BaseApplication.getInstance().getApplicationMode() == ApplicationMode.DEVELOPMENT) {
        builder.baseUrl(NetworkURLs.BASE_URL_UAT);
    } else {
        builder.baseUrl(NetworkURLs.BASE_URL_PRODUCTION);
    }


    builder.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create());
    builder.client(okHttpClient);
    builder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));


    return builder.build();
}
```

for example
This is url : https://gethelp.wildapricot.com/en/articles/549-changing-your

baseURL : https://gethelp.wildapricot.com

Remaining @Url: /en/articles/549-changing-your (which is you pass in retro service class)

Answer (score 7):

**Step-1**

```
  Please define a method in Api interface like:-
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST()
 Call<RootLoginModel> getForgotPassword(
        @Url String apiname,
        @Field(ParameterConstants.email_id) String username
 );
```

**Step-2** 
          For a best practice define a class for retrofit instance:-

```
  public class ApiRequest {
       static Retrofit retrofit = null;



public static Retrofit getClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URLConstants.base_url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}
**Step-3** 
             define in your activity:-

```
  final APIService request =ApiRequest.getClient().create(APIService.class);
  Call<RootLoginModel> call = request.getForgotPassword("dynamic api 
  name",strEmailid);
```

Answer (score 5):

[RetrofitHelper](https://github.com/G-Corporation/RetrofitHelper) library written in kotlin, will let you make API calls, using a few lines of code and you can use **different URLs, Headers and Params**, in every Call.

Add multiple URLs in your application class like this :

```
class Application : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

        retrofitClient = RetrofitClient.instance
                // api url
                .setBaseUrl("https://reqres.in/")
                // you can set multiple urls
                // .setUrl("example","http://ngrok.io/api/")
                // set timeouts
                .setConnectionTimeout(4)
                .setReadingTimeout(15)
                // enable cache
                .enableCaching(this)
                // add Headers
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("client", "android")
                .addHeader("language", Locale.getDefault().language)
                .addHeader("os", android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE)
            }

        companion object {
        lateinit var retrofitClient: RetrofitClient

        }
    }
```

And then use the URL you need in your call:

```kotlin
retrofitClient.Get<GetResponseModel>()
            // set base url
            .setBaseUrlKey("example")
            // set path
            .setPath("api/users/2")
            // set url params Key-Value or HashMap
            .setUrlParams("KEY","Value")
            .setResponseHandler(GetResponseModel::class.java,
                object : ResponseHandler<GetResponseModel>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(response: Response<GetResponseModel>) {
                        super.onSuccess(response)
                        //handle response
                    }
                }).run(this)
```

For more information see the [documentation](https://github.com/G-Corporation/RetrofitHelper/wiki)

Answer (score 4):

If you already have your code setup and you don’t want to make changes on the different interfaces you can, use the solution described in this [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-change-api-base-url-at-runtime-2).
The main point is the method `changeApiBaseUrl` that updates the URL and recreates the Retrofit builder.

```
public class ServiceGenerator {  
public static String apiBaseUrl = "http://futurestud.io/api";
private static Retrofit retrofit;

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl);

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
        new OkHttpClient.Builder();

// No need to instantiate this class.
private ServiceGenerator() {
}

public static void changeApiBaseUrl(String newApiBaseUrl) {
    apiBaseUrl = newApiBaseUrl;

    builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl);
}

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, AccessToken token) {
    String authToken = token.getTokenType().concat(token.getAccessToken());
    return createService(serviceClass, authToken);
}

// more methods
// ...
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
public class DynamicBaseUrlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = "CallInstances";
private Callback<ResponseBody> downloadCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_upload);

    downloadCallback = new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "server contacted at: " + call.request().url());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "call failed against the url: " + call.request().url());
        }
    };

    // first request
    FileDownloadService downloadService = ServiceGenerator.create(FileDownloadService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> originalCall = downloadService.downloadFileWithFixedUrl();
    originalCall.enqueue(downloadCallback);

    // change base url
    ServiceGenerator.changeApiBaseUrl("http://development.futurestud.io/api");

    // new request against new base url
    FileDownloadService newDownloadService = ServiceGenerator.create(FileDownloadService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> newCall = newDownloadService.downloadFileWithFixedUrl();
    newCall.enqueue(downloadCallback);
    }
}
```