# Retrofit2 - Can't get basic authentication for webAPI with dynamic URL

Tags: android, json, basic-authentication, retrofit2

I'm familiar with how to use dynamic URLs with Retrofit2 but having issue sending username & password in the request. The webAPI works by entering a URL, a login prompt appears on the screen for a username & password, after authentication a JSON response is displayed. The interface is defined for a dynamic URL:

```
@GET
public Call<User> getJSON(@Url String string);
```

My request is as follows:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    LoginService service = retrofit.create(LoginService.class);

    Call<User> call = service.getJSON("https://username:password@api.url.com/");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, retrofit2.Response<User> response) {
            System.out.println("Response status code: " + response.code());
```

I'm certain the URL is correct as it works in the browser & but I keep getting error the username & password aren't correct?

```
I/System.out: Response status code: 401
```

Also, as far as I can tell I can only use @GET rather than @POST because whenever I try @POST the response code is:

```
I/System.out: Response status code: 405
```

At first I tried to follow something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url) using an encoded flag because it's an example of how to use @PATH & @URL with Retrofit2 but didn't have any success. That's why I tried the username:password@ prepend to the URL. Most of the other examples all use the @POST method.

Any feedback or ideas on how I can authenticate? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to do it in retrofit, but you can add it via an OkHttp interceptor --

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addNetworkInterceptor(
    new Interceptor() {
      @Override
      public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        HttpUrl url = request.url();
        url = url.newBuilder().username("username").password("password").build();
        Request newRequest = request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
      }
    }
).build();
```

be sure to add this client to your retrofit instance --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .baseUrl(API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks @iagreen for your help, now I'm able to successfully authenticate

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use basic authentication with Retrofit2 would be to pass the authentication string as an argument to your interface method.

So you would change the method signature to:

```
@GET
public Call<User> getJSON(@Url String string, @Header("Authorization") String myAuthString);
```

And then call it like this:

```
Call<User> call = service.getJSON("https://api.url.com/", "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==");
```

Where you substitute `QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==` for your Base64-encoded `username:password` string.

If you need to pass the username and password for every API call and want to keep the method signatures clean, it might be better to use the custom `OkHttpInterceptor` method instead.

Comment: I'll give it a try @Frakur. Always nice to have more than one way to get it done.