# com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am using retrofit with GSON for the first time.It is Running Fluently with static data but it is showing the above error in the Case of the Dynamic Data.It is Showing error in the Adapter on setting the Text value

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String Navigation_Url = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com";
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<ListPojo> listPojos = new ArrayList<>();
    ListRetrofitAndroid listRetrofitAndroid;


    ArrayList countries = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        getRetrofitData();
    }


    void getRetrofitData() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Navigation_Url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        CountryArrayAPI api = retrofit.create(CountryArrayAPI.class);
        Call<List> call = api.getCountries();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List> call, Response<List> response) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                try {
                    listPojos = (ArrayList) response.body();
                    System.out.println("the ArrayList is" + listPojos);


//                    ArrayList<ListPojo> merchantOfferModels = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ListPojo>() {}.getType());









                    listRetrofitAndroid = new ListRetrofitAndroid(getApplicationContext(), listPojos);
                    listView.setAdapter(listRetrofitAndroid);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Failure", t.toString());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**ListRetrofitAndroid(Adapter)**

```
public class ListRetrofitAndroid extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ListPojo> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";


    public ListRetrofitAndroid(Context context, ArrayList<ListPojo> listPojos) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
        this.arrayList = listPojos;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {


        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            //  viewHolder = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder();
            viewHolder = new Holder();
            viewHolder.textName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_main);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        } else {

            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.textName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());


        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView textName;
    }


}
```

**model(ListPojo)**

```
public class ListPojo {

    String title;

    public ListPojo(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

**interface**

```
public interface CountryArrayAPI {
    @GET("/api/popular_destinations")
    public Call<List> getCountries();
}
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hiranya Varna Mahavihar",
        "location": "Kwalakhu Rd, Patan 44600, Nepal",
        "main_image": "images/popular_places/patan-durbar-square.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Yasodhar Mahavihar-Bubahal",
        "location": "Jana Bahal Rd, Patan 44600, Nepal",
        "main_image": "images/popular_places/patan-durbar-square.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Krishna Temple Sundhara",
        "location": "Tyagal - Lalitpur Rd, Patan 44600, Nepal",
        "main_image": "images/popular_places/Patan-2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Hiranya Varna Mahavihar",
        "location": "Kwalakhu Rd, Patan 44600, Nepal",
        "main_image": "images/popular_places/asd.jpg"
    }
]
```

**StsckTrace**

```
09-19 05:15:32.475 18949-18949/com.example.user_pc.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.user_pc.myapplication, PID: 18949
                                                                                   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.example.user_pc.myapplication.pojo.ListPojo
                                                                                       at com.example.user_pc.myapplication.adpater.ListRetrofitAndroid.getView(ListRetrofitAndroid.java:71)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                       at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                                                                                       at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `ArrayList<ListPojo>` so you need to make sure that the parsing should happen using right type `List<ListPojo>` instead of `list` which has no type

due to the missing type information , `gson` is returning a `List` of internally 
created objects `LinkedTreeMap` and since you are using `raw` types (should be a warning for unchecked cast)with declaration as concrete type which will create a issue when adapter actually expecting a `PojoObject` but internally it's something else. so solution

[`Never use raw-types anywhere possible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it?answertab=votes#tab-top)

so do

```
public interface CountryArrayAPI {
    @GET("api/popular_destinations")
    public Call<List<ListPojo>> getCountries();
}
```

and also remove `/` before `api` and call will be like

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ListPojo>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ListPojo>> call, Response<List<ListPojo>> response) {
            listPojos = response.body();
```

and always code to `interface` so

```
List<ListPojo> listPojos = ...;
```

Comment: thank you mate thats working .Can you elaborate more about my problem.That would be a great help.

Comment: as i modified my answer ,in short you are using `List` which has no type parameter so no parsing will take place and you get list of undesired type objects , so never use raw type `List`

Comment: i am glad that i could help pal , happy coding

Comment: I do have one qeuiry, in my mind that , in case of using the interface .can't i add the url on the Same Method where i usually get response .

Comment: yes you can , either you can use placeholders `{}` or complete urls , see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url

Comment: this helps a lot. i am going to dig into retrofit. :)

Comment: I wasted 12 hours on this issue. I want to thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I currently exactly don't know how to handle the json using `List`. But you can use array like this:

```
public interface CountryArrayAPI {
    @GET("/api/popular_destinations")
    public Call<ListPojo[]> getCountries();
}
```

Comment: sure nabin i will check this