# Android: Using Retrofit with dynamic urls

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have an url similar to `http://www.myexample.com/rss/choose.php?type=level&id=2` and I want to use Retrofit in my android app. The problem is that `type` is a parameter which can take different values like `level`, `grade`, etc.
I can't adapt Retrofit every time `type` change because I get a "Annotations are not allowed here" in TestesInterface. I was looking to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url) and applied to my app but it doesn't work.

```
static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.myexample.com/rss/";

public void start() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create()).build();

    TestesInterface testesInterface = retrofit.create(TestesInterface.class);

    Call<Channel> call = testesInterface.loadChannel("choose.php?type=level&id=2");
    call.enqueue(this);
}
```

My interface:

```
public interface TestesInterface {
    @GET
    Call<Channel> loadChannel(@Url type);
}
```

This made that every time I want to change type to a different value I should change `testesInterface.loadChannel("choose.php?type=level&id=2")`. This doesn't work. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try different approaches I got the solution. 
I had to use the tag `@Query` to `type` and `id` on interface and send the values when I'm invoking it in start():

```
@GET
Call<Channel> loadChannel(@Query("type") String type,
                          @Query("id") String value);
```