# How to change Value dynamically in @GET annotation?

Tags: android, annotations, retrofit

I am using `Retrofit` for download APK file from the server.

Below is code snippet.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Util.APK_DOWNLOAD_URL)
                .build();

        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> request = retrofitInterface.downloadFile();
        try {

            downloadFile(request.execute().body());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

And

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @GET("development/filename.apk")
    @Streaming
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile();
}
```

But there is problem.

Download APK is always different.
So

How can I set Some `public static String` in

```
@GET(Utils.APK_FILE_NAME)
```

And in my Utils class

```
public static String APK_FILE_NAME = ""
```

Currently I am getting

> Attribute Value Must be Constant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 2 - Dynamic URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use @Path annotation for example:

```
@GET("development/{filename}")
@Streaming
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Path("filename") String filename;
```

and

```
String filename;
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Util.APK_DOWNLOAD_URL)
                .build();

        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> request = retrofitInterface.downloadFile(filename);
        try {

            downloadFile(request.execute().body());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it dynamic by passing it as parameter instead of declaring it at annotation as in

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
    @Streaming
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Url String filename);
}
```

Now you can access it at run time using

```
 Call<ResponseBody> request = retrofitInterface.downloadFile(Utils.APK_FILE_NAME);
```

Comment: Exception Occurred. Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., GET, POST, etc.). for method RetrofitInterface.downloadFile

Answer (score 1):

one way to pass string is using @Path annotation:

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
  @GET("{APK_FILE_NAME}")
  Call<Users> getUsers(@Path(value = "APK_FILE_NAME", encoded = true) String apk_file_name);
}
```

For more detail use following link,
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html