# How can I set Android Retrofit2 BASE URL taking values of EditText from an activity?

Tags: android, retrofit2, base-url

I have an activity from where I'm getting base url ip like 10.0.2.2 and port 8080 through two different `EditText`.
 Now I'm making a url string from the obtained values like `http://10.0.2.2:8080`.
 Now I need to set this url as `ApiClient()` *BASE_URL*. This url will be permanent. It should be available all over the app in any activity or any fragment. 
 
NOTE: **I need to Set the value only single time of Application Life Time.**
If you suggest a `Singleton Class` or by `SharedPreference` please explain with source. (I've tried with them but it didn't worked perfectly)

Comment: as far as I know we cannot change the base url, but we can alter the url when sending a request, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url

Comment: I don't want to change the base url. I just need to set the base url on run time when the app runs for the first time taking the values from `EditText` input.

Comment: you can set the url at the request with @Url parameter, like in this link  stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url

Comment: This is not what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above problem, best solution is to store the information in `SQLite` or `Room` Database or manually store the information in a file in Phone Storage.

Using `SharedPreferences` it can be done also. In this case the `ApiClient`
should have a Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class and define static variables with better and better.
And initialize those variable when you get value from edit text and then you can simply get value from that static 
And in your activity class you access like this
baseurl.Setip(your edit text value)
And to get that ip you can write 
Retrofit.Builder.baseurl(baseurl.getIp)
Something like this
[Hope this image will explain you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivmVS.jpg)

Comment: I tried it. This process works only for the first time. But after the app destroys the information is lost. So better to use SQLite Database or store the information in a File in phone storage. BTW thanks for your answer.

Comment: then you can use SharedPreferences for storing this url and if you want i can share the syntax to store and retrive sharedpreference

Comment: Shared preference is only accessible from Activity. So in this case you can't get value from shared preference.

Comment: @Mehedi shared preference can also be accessed from a java class just need to Extend with context