# How i change the retrofit URL at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, koin

I need change the URL base in retrofit, i'm using koin to create a retrofit module on app startup and i want change this url in runtime.

I already tried change the baseUrl("http://192.168.192.168/") to baseUrl("http://")and change the url on retrofit call but my app crashs and return illegal URL error.

This is my fun to create the builder

```
fun createRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return  Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://192.168.192.168/")//i need change this at runtime
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
.build()
}
```

create a bean to my module

```
val retrofitModule: Module = applicationContext {
    bean { createRetrofit(get()) }
}
```

and start the koin:

```
startKoin(application = this,
  modules = listOf(retrofitModule, ...)
)
```

someone  can i help me with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have to add these lines in your code:

**First Step:**
Add the new CallAdapter **RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()** when building a Retrofit instance.

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://google.com/";
public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

**Next step:**
Update the **APIService** for example:-> *savePost(String title, String body, String userId)* method to become an Observable.

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> list(@Url String url);
//or

@POST("/posts")
@FormUrlEncoded
Observable<Post> savePost(@Field("title") String title,
                          @Field("body") String body,
                          @Field("userId") long userId);
}
```

**Final step:**
When making the requests, our anonymous subscriber responds to the observable's stream which emits event.

```
public void sendPost(String title, String body) {

    // RxJava
    mAPIService.savePost(title, body, 1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Post post) {
                    showResponse(post.toString());
                }
            });
}
```

this is way you build your dynamic urls: want to learn more details full description link: **[Sending Data With Retrofit 2 HTTP Client for Android](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845)**

and See [base URL](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#baseUrl-okhttp3.HttpUrl-) for details of how the value will be resolved against a base URL to create the full endpoint URL.

if you are doing using kotlin: follow this link. [dynamic urls at Runtime with Retrofit 2](https://medium.com/@serapbercin001/how-to-use-dynamic-urls-at-runtime-with-retrofit-2-4ebb71c7e34d)

Answer (score 1):

> I already tried change the baseUrl("http://192.168.192.168/") to baseUrl("http://")and change the url on retrofit call but my app crashs and return illegal URL error.

You can leave it as a `baseUrl` if you use `@URL` it will overwrite the one on yout `Retrofit.Builder()`

You can use `@URL` parameter to change the endpoint dynamically.

```
@GET
fun getUsers(@Url String url) : Observable<UserResponse>
```