# Retrofit2 - Endpoint with variables in URI

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to get to grips with retrofit2. I'm trying to do an API call to the  following url:

```
https://baseurl.com/api/user/{user_id}/devices
```

How do I psas the `user_id` variable to the endpoint?

```
@GET("/api/user/<<some magic>>/devices") // please help
```

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). The first example shows how.

Comment: Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55860010/115145 is what you want.