# Hilt reinitialise application module object

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

We are generating retrofit having application scope. Now user can select two options, which will change base url. As retrofit instance is created on start of application, how can we change the base url of same retrofit instance or recreate new retrofit instance. Recreating it this time will update url from Shared Preference

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url